# Adding individual float values per UITableViewCell to get grand totals?

Tags: core-data, uitableview

I am having a major problem even getting started with finding an answer to this question? I have a UITableView that is being populated by user generated content and being persisted to CoreData. All is good. However I can't even find a way in the Apple docs to do the following:

How do I add each dollar value in a cell to get a grand total displayed somewhere to the user? In this case it can be thrown in a UILabel in the footer of each section I don't care. What I can't figure out is how to get to each individual cell get the dollar amount entered there and add it to the next dollar amount in the next cell in the section and so on.

Any ideas on how to add totals from cells to get a grand total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution to this problem is using key paths.

You do not go to the cells and get the data out. You go to your data model and calculate it from there. Remember, MVC dictates that you should always separate model and view.

Suppose you have a subclass of NSManagedObject with an NSNumber attribute "amount" fetched via core data. You can then easily do simple calculations like this:

```
float sum = [[fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"] floatValue];
```

This is described in the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide under [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: That is a powerful line of code. I will certainly read more in collection operators from the link provided. Thanks!